# Turn off wireless light

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm trying to get my wireless light to turn out on my Dreamplug, I've tried using the command sys_cfg_ctl 1 but it still stays on (AP is not visible anymore though). I'm assuming there's another command that I'm missing but not sure what it might be. I'm running Ubuntu currently.